# Text object not showing up in a javafx scene Window object

Tags: java, javafx, text, stage

I got a class in my project that `extends` the `Application` class and when I run the program it draws the window but does not display the text as expected in its content pane. Here is what I tried...

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
     stage.setTitle("Web Crawler");
     Text mytext= new Text("Output will show up here");
     //Create a new Spider object and then call method to return strin
     mytext.setText("My name is professional programmer");
     mytext.setVisible(true);
     Group root= new Group();
     root.getChildren().add(mytext);
       stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
      stage.show();
    }
```

Comment: don't use Group as parent (at least not until you fully understand layouts :) - instead use an appropriate layout, f.i. a VBox or a BorderPane with the text in center.

Comment: Okay thanks, will try VBox and BorderPane